# TinyMCE lists removes classes

Tags: tinymce

I am using style_formats to apply specific styles like classes to selected texts inside the editor. These styles for example change the size of the font.

This works fine however when I change the line to a numlist or a bullet list it loses the classes and the wrapper around it.

For example this is before I apply a list:

```
<div class="text-auto"><span class="text-xl">Text message</span><br></div>
```

When selecting numlist or bullet list it turns into :

```
<div class="text-auto"><ul><li>Text message<br></li></ul></div>
```

As you can see the span with class text-xl is lost.

Is there a way I can make sure that the span gets transfered to the LI with the class applied? If not, perhaps get the class from the span applied to the LI in question.

Comment: Have you tried `style_formats_merge` option ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing it unfortunately